# JAVA: Initialize Object Class

Tags: java

I'm new learner in programming, and i have a logic problem.

I would like to initialize a object class to settle it.

I have 2 Entities object Class:

**Entity1:**

```
private Date date;
private List<Entity2> entity2;

      .... Getters and Setters ....
```

**Entity2:**

```
private String description;

      .... Getters and Setters ....
```

Now I've init the entities

```
Entity1 entity1 = new Entity1();
List<Entity2> Entity2 = new ArrayList<Entity2>();

entity1.setEntity2(entity2);
```

I have no error message by doing this, in debugging mode I see in the entity1 and the ArrayList of entity2, but empty. I see no object inside, just this **[ ]** and I would like to see **"description"** object (which will be normal), like this **[description = null];**

Someone can explain to me what I do wrong ?

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Where are you adding anything to the `ArrayList` ?

Comment: That's because you haven't added any objects in the `List<Entity2> Entity2` you created

Comment: @Shrey Garg     hummm ... I should add settle entity2 before initialaze it ?

Comment: You should create objects of `Entity2` class and add them to your `entity2` list after initialising your list with `new ArrayList<Entity2>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close. Let's consider what you've got thus far.

```
Entity1 entity1 = new Entity1();
```

You've created yourself an instance of `Entity1`. So far, this looks like this:

```
{
    Date: null,
    entity2: null
}
```

Then you've issued the following commands:

```
List<Entity2> Entity2 = new ArrayList<Entity2>();

entity1.setEntity2(entity2);
```

So now your `entity1` variable looks like this:

```
{
    Date: null,
    entity2: [],
}
```

The next thing you need to do is add a new object into your new list. First, you need to make yourself an instance of `Entity2`.

```
Entity2 myEntity = new Entity2();
```

Then you need to put it into your list, using the `add` command on the `List` interface. I won't write this out for you, you need to work it out yourself. Have fun!

Comment: **Thanks so much !!** to christopher and @Shrey Garg       I did ```entity2.add(myEntity)``` and it works perfectly ...

Comment: Happy to help, thank you for accepting!